# Is the projection map from direct product of projective $n$ space and projective $m$ space to projective $n$ space a closed map?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, projective-space

Is the projection map from direct product of projective $n$ space and projective $m$ space to projective $n$ space a closed map? I know that if $X$, and $Y$ are topological spaces with the product topology on the direct product and if $Y$ is compact then the projection onto $X$ is closed. But the problem here is that the topology on direct product of projective $n$ space and projective $m$ space is not the box topology.

Comment: Yes. Projective morphisms are proper. In particular, they are universally closed. More generally, if $X\to Y$ is proper, then the projection $X\times_Y Z\to Z$ is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for the "Fundamental Theorem of Elimination Theory" in Ravi's notes on algebraic geometry. You can find these [here.](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/)